# ReSharper and NUnit's multiple domains

Tags: nunit, resharper

I recently had to enable this option in ReSharper:

> Use separate AppDomain for each assembly with tests

Looking at the NUnit documentation, I suspect the option above executes NUnit with the parameter "domain/multiple", for which "a separate test domain is created for each assembly".

Could you please confirm me that is true?

Comment: I assumed that resharper had its own test runner implementation rather than calling out to nunit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this option corresponds to the `/domain=Multiple` command line parameter.

Note that ReSharper doesn't use the console runner. Instead it directly links the NUnit assemblies.